# OpenGL Multiple Render Targets with multiple gl_Position output

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm looking for a MRT where I can write to my buffers at different position.

### Example

**Buffer 0 :**
gl_Position[0] = vec4(uv,0.,1.);
gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1.);

**Buffer 1 :**
gl_Position[1] = MVP * pos;
gl_FragData[1] = vec4(0.);

Is it possible to have multiple output in a vertex shader ?
I can't find any resources about that..

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to have multiple output in a vertex shader ?

No, but that doesn't mean you can't get the effect of what you want. Well, you didn't describe in any real detail what you wanted, but this is as close as OpenGL can provide.

What you want seems rather like [layered rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layered_Rendering). It is the ability of a *Geometry Shader* to generate primitives that go to different layers. So you can generate one triangle that renders to one layer, then generate a second triangle that goes to a different layer.

Of course, that raises a question: what's a layer? Well, that has to do with [layered framebuffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layered_Framebuffer). See, if you attach a layered image to a framebuffer (an [array texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) or [cubemap texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture)), each array layer/cubemap face represents a different 2D layer that can be rendered to. The Geometry Shader can send each output primitive to a specific layer in the layered framebuffer. So if you have 3 array layers in an image, your GS can output a primitive to layer 0, 1, or 2, and that primitive will only be rendered to that particular image in the array texture.

Depth buffers can be layered as well, and you *must* use a layered depth buffer if you want to have depth testing work at all with layered rendering. All aspects of the primitive's rendering are governed by the layer it gets send to. So when the fragment shader is run, the outputs will go only to the layer it was rendered to. When the depth test is done, the read for that test will only read from that layer of the depth buffer. And so on, including blending.

Of course, using layered framebuffers means that all of the layers in a particular image attachment have to be from the same texture. And therefore they must have the same [Image Format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). So there are limitations. But overall, it more or less does what you asked.